# Can I use IPyWidgets to pass arguments to the command line?

Tags: python, user-interface, jupyter, ipywidgets

I downloaded a deep learning script from GitHub in order to perform some text classification on tweets. Neural Nets go kind of over my head but I get along by using this script.

Let's say the file is called main.py and it takes command line arguments such as:

*-t*  and *-i "path/to/tweet/corpus"* and a bunch of other flags.

I wanted to make an interactive Jupyter notebook with IPyWidgets so that if someone enters *'folder/to/tweets/'* in the text box widget, and then pushes a button or runs a cell, it will pass that string to the command line including the -i flag.

I tried the following:

```
# CELL 1
texboxt_1 = widgets.Text(
    value='/path/to/corpus/',
    placeholder='Type something',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)

texboxt_2 = widgets.Text(
    value='/path/to/model/',
    placeholder='Type something',
    description='String:',
    disabled=False
)

#CELL 2
if texbox_1.value != '':
   arg_1 = '-i' + textbox_1.value
else:
   arg_1 = ''

if textbox_2.value != '':
   arg_2 = arg_1 + '-m' + textbox_2.value
else:
   arg_2 = ''


# CELL 3
!python main.py {arg_1 + arg_2}
```

I guess this will work but it doesn't seem like the smartest and/or most efficient way to pass arguments. Could I do it any other way? or is there something in main.py I could alter to smoothen the process?

As you could probably tell I'm just an amateur python user.

Comment: Could you import the relevant functions from the NN script, and call it yourself directly, without requiring use of the command line? What is in the `if __name__ == '__main__':` section of the script?